# java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent (HTC voice dictation)

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Folks,

I wrote a speech recognition app using android's built-in speech recognition classes. Once in a while the following exception shows up in my developer console when the startListening function is called on the speech recognizer object obtained using createSpeechRecognizer(context) function.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent {     act=android.speech.RecognitionService cmp=com.htc.android.voicedictation/.VoiceDictationService }
```

I do not own a HTC device... so any ideas why this is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?